# No Routes found for Locations soft-restricted network element

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I am using OD Cost Matrix to find the least cost path for a number of locations and destinations.

There are few Origins that have this warning: 
"Warning: Location "Location123" in "Origins" is on a soft-restricted network element."

And no Routes are found for these Origins.

I looked up in my map so make sure that the location is covered by network roads and it seems find on the map: 
[image]
I tried to Google what does "soft-restricted network element" mean but could not really find anything online.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Look at the attributes of the road edge to which the location is snapped. If you have any soft restrictions on this edge (such as "avoid local roads" etc), which you can check in the network dataset properties window (Analysis tab), then you might need to reload your locations while specifying the snapping options (exclude those edges that are of type "local road"). This will snap them to another closely located road edge.